# Windows Server 2012 R2 Drag Drop Icons

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, drag-and-drop, windows-server-2012

This question is specifically for Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2. Like so many other versions of windows, the default behavior is to render the largest icons possible during drag and drop. How do you change the display settings in Windows 2012 so that the icons are a useful, smaller size or turn off the icons altogether? The pages explaining how to do this in Window 7, Window 8, and Window 10 do not seem to apply to Windows Server 2012 R2. What features must be uninstalled or what registry hacks must be performed to make the large icons go away?